# "Availability status: error" for working C programs

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw-w64

I recently learned about Visual Studio Code & Intellisense and am currently writing code on that and trying to compile it using Cygwin. However, I'm never able to do it.

I have added `C:\cygwin64\bin` and `%systemdrive%:\cygwin\bin` to my system environment variables in settings. I'm doing this on a Windows 11 computer. But every time I try to compile a program, like:

```
gcc HelloWorld.c
```

I get:

```
cc1: fatal error: HelloWorld.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

In file explorer, all the programs I'm trying to compile say "Availability status: error". Specifically, any programs (regardless of language) I have downloaded onto my computer hard drive are apparently unavailable. What does this mean?

I tried using MSYS Mingw-w64 but the same problem happens. I thought that I might not have included the "gcc-core" compiler file when I downloaded it, so i did that again with the file but nothing. I typed `gcc --version` and `gdb -- version` to check and debug but the same messages pop up, both for Cygwin and Mingw.

I tried using other text editors (notepad and vim) to type, but they didn't have any effect. I thought they might create compileable, "available" files on file explorer.

Comment: Where (in what path, and in what window) do you input the command "gcc HelloWorld.c"?

Comment: It seems your file `HelloWorld.c` doe snot exist.

Comment: "to my system environment variables in settings" What does that mean? Did you (or some installer) add it to PATH? As in, if you open the command prompt and type "path", do you see the gcc path there?

Comment: The problem is most likely this mysterious _"Availability status: error"._ Where exactly does this show up. It's certainly totally unrelated to gcc.

Comment: Instead of `gcc HelloWorld.c` try `type HelloWorld.c` and tell us what happens.

Comment: This sounds like problems with OneDrive which is totally unrelated to C. Read this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-file-explorer-availability-statuserror/848b744f-cf8c-4f6c-a4bd-c2c156cf5c2b

Comment: To answer "Lundin"'s question, I clicked Settings > Edit the system environment variables (in the search bar) > Environment variables (in the "Advanced" tab) > PATH . I pressed edit, made a new path variable. But I only see the PATH for my personal computer's account when I open the command prompt. (i.e. LJH10@LAPTOP-CCRGKHIM  is what I see)

Comment: @c_and_me1 please do what I suggested.

Comment: I typed type HelloWorld.c and nothing happened.

Comment: I have also looked on the website you attached, thank you. I found that my onedrive was full, and I deleted enough space to hold more programs. However, the "availability status: error" message has gone away, but I still get "cc1: fatal error: HelloWorld.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

Comment: @c_and_me1 Instead of `gcc HelloWorld.c` try `type HelloWorld.c` and tell us what happens.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the text editor. The error message simply means that the file does not exist. I guess a `ls HelloWorld.c` also yields this error? @Jabberwocky: A `type` command does not make sense, as it is intended for searching something **executable**.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, `type HelloWorld.c` makes sense because it will most likely show an error message which the OP should then post as a comment, and which would allow us to move on.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: In Cygwin, this can be misleading. Due to the mismatch of Windows- and Unix-access model, it happens easily that you by chance created a text file which, when seen from `stat`, has the x-bit being set. On my platform, this happens for instance when I create a text file using my Windows editor.  In the OPs case, we are interested in knowing, whether the file is in the working directory, and in this case, a `ls` or `stat` would be IMO the better way to check.

Comment: $ ls HelloWorld.c
ls: cannot access 'HelloWorld.c': No such file or directory

Comment: It turns out that several other commands, like pow, ls, run, and stat return similar error messages. I'll have to reinstall Cygwin with all necessary packages again to fix this. Thank you guys for your time and patience.